# Is there an existing database of mutation rates for mitochondrial loci?

Tags: population-genetics, mutations

I'm wondering if there exists a database of mutation rates (transitions and transversions) for both mitochondrial loci (such as cytochrome c oxidase subunit I (COI)).

Due to the use of COI as a DNA barcode to identify animal species, this gene has a relatively high mutation rate despite being quite conserved across major taxonomic groups. Thus, substitutions in COI are expected to become diagnostic of species much more rapidly (also because of the 4-fold lower effective population size compared to nuclear markers).

The reason I ask is because I am developing a simulation algorithm allowing a user to generate random DNA sequences under a specified nucleotide evolution model (e.g., Jukes-Cantor, Kimura-2-Parameter). I would like to be able to specify realistic mutation rates of transitions and transversions in order to closely mirror actual substitution rates in COI.

Any insight would be much appreciated